# Jasmine add custom message to protractor report

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor, warnings

I am looking the way how to add custom message to jasmine HTML report. This should be additional information which should be just stored in report. So basically it will be something like warnings, or some information like object name that I've created.

Note: expect('1').toBe('1','this is failure message'); - is working, but I need to have possibility sometimes add some information to reports. ( this mean that I don't want to write CustomReporter).

Comment: So basically I need to have possibility to add custom messages even in case of passed expects

Comment: Try https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston